# Aws dynamo db mapper is not converting data

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, microservices

log audit method is trying to covert complex json string into map to store data in the form of json into dynamodb table but ending with error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue

class AuditService{

```
            @Autowired
            AuditRepository auditRepository;
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            public void logAudit(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
                
            Audit audit= new Audit();
            // coverting complex json string to map with help of mapper 
            audit.setEncryptedRequest(mapper.readValue(complex_multiLevel_json_String, new TypeReference<Map>() {})
            
            audit.save();
            }
          }  
            @Setter
            @Getter
            @Data
            @Builder
            @NoArgsConstructor
            @AllArgsConstructor
            @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Audit")
            class Audit{
            ------
            ------
            ------
             private Map<String, AttributeValue> encryptedRequest;
             @DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.DynamoDBAttributeType.M)
                public Map<String, AttributeValue> getEncryptedRequest() {
                    return encryptedPiiRequest;
                }
            
                public void setEncryptedPiiRequest(Map<String, AttributeValue> encryptedRequest) {
                    this.encryptedRequest = encryptedRequest;
                }
                }








complex json string which need to store into dynamo db table in the form of map:
```

note : we don't want to create a model class with below json attribute as field and then storing those model class to dynamo db

```
"{
    "customers": [
        {
            "applicant": {
                "fName": "Duck",
                "lName": "PJOHN",
                "dob": "19270101",
                "ssn": "666455649",
                "suffix": ""
            },
            "phone": [
                {
                    "number": 4239506,
                    "type": "R"
                }
            ],
            "cAddress": {
                "line1": "5  LONG DR",
                "zipCode": 37604
            },
            "pAddress": {
                "line1": "100, Main St",
                "Code": 12345
            }
        }
    ],
    "iteam": {
        "Source": "amazon",
        "Type": "BOTH"
    }
}"



error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$Rules$NativeType.set(StandardModelFactories.java:212) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$AbstractRule.convert(StandardModelFactories.java:709) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$AbstractRule.convert(StandardModelFactories.java:691) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$DelegateConverter.convert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:104) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$NullSafeConverter.convert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:123) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$DelegateConverter.convert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:104) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$Rules$1.convert(StandardModelFactories.java:682) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$Rules$1.convert(StandardModelFactories.java:680) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$Vector$ToMap.convert(StandardTypeConverters.java:425) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$Vector$ToMap$1.convert(StandardTypeConverters.java:413) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$Vector$ToMap$1.convert(StandardTypeConverters.java:410) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$DelegateConverter.convert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:104) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$NullSafeConverter.convert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:123) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$ExtendedConverter.convert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:83) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.convert(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:138) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:739) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:641) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.save(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:123) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.573.jar:na]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.core.DynamoDBTemplate.save(DynamoDBTemplate.java:146) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.SimpleDynamoDBCrudRepository.save(SimpleDynamoDBCrudRepository.java:115) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.
```

Answer (score 0):

One way can be to store your audit data in base64 encoded attribute to be generic. But this implies decoding it when it`s read.